# How to mass search excel files for a string and return the cell next to it?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter

I've got to find a "part number" in a bit over 1.4k excel files. They're all formatted slightly differently, so I can't just call for the cell location. What is consistent is the value I'm looking for is always in the cell next to "part number". What I've been trying to do is roughly:

```
open excel file in folder
search all rows
if str(cell value) = "part number" 
print("filename" + cell row+1) in another excel file
loop until done
```

I'm rather amateur at this and I've looked at quite a few videos, but none describe exactly what I'm trying to accomplish. All of the files only have 1 sheet.

edit:
The files I'm working with are .xls, so I had to import xlrd instead.

I tried this

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

def do_your_task(filename):
    wb = open_workbook(filename = '8307922.xls')  # load work book
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # get active work sheet
    for row in ws.rows:  # iterate over each row
        for cell in row:  # iterate over each cell in the row
            if cell.value == "part number":  # find "part number"
                return ws.cells(row=cell.row_idx, column=cell.col_idx).value  # get the value of the next cell
    return None

for root, _, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\sdiaz\Desktop\Active'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            print(file, do_your_task(file))
```

and got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [75], in <cell line: 12>()
     13 for file in files:
     14     if file.endswith('.xls'):
---> 15         print(file, do_your_task(file))

Input In [75], in do_your_task(filename)
      4 wb = open_workbook(filename = '8307922.xls')  # load work book
      5 ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # get active work sheet
----> 6 for row in ws.rows:  # iterate over each row
      7     for cell in row:  # iterate over each cell in the row
      8         if cell.value == "part number":  # find "part number"

AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'rows'
```

I get now that I've got to change the wb.active section, but not sure how.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a library for this. For example, `xlrd`, `xlsxwriter` or `openpyxl` can read and write Excel files. They also provide means of accessing and iterating rows. They basically work similar, To find out how to use them, you can study their documentation and try to understand their introductory examples.

For example, [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html):

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def do_your_task(filename):
    wb = load_workbook(filename)  # load work book
    ws = wb.active  # get active work sheet
    for row in ws.rows:  # iterate over each row
        for cell in row:  # iterate over each cell in the row
            if cell.value == "part number":  # find "part number"
                return ws.cells(row=cell.row_idx, column=cell.col_idx).value  # get the value of the next cell
    return None

for root, _, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            print(file, do_your_task(file))
```

Although they basically work similar, their APIs aren't the same. If you want to use `xlrd`, you need a range-based for loop:

```
import xlrd

def do_your_task(filename):
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(filename)  # load work book
    ws = wb.sheet_by_index(0)  # get a work sheet
    for row_id in range(ws.nrows):  # iterate over each row
        for col_id, cell in enumerate(sh.row(row_id)):  # iterate over each cell in the row
            if cell.value == "part number":  # find "part number"
                return ws.cell(row_id, col_id).value  # get the value of the next cell
    return None

for root, _, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xls'):
            print(file, do_your_task(file))
```

Comment: I had to use xlrd because they were .xls files. I added what I tried and the traceback.

thank you

Comment: Although the libraries work conceptually similar, their APIs are different. You cannot use my example 1:1 with `xlrd` or `xlsxwriter`. Checkout the [documentation of xlrd](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). They have a small example which iterates over the rows.